# Using Eigenvalues to prove a matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

In regard to eigenvalues and eigenvectors in Linear Algebra, 
How can I prove that the characteristic equation of a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ can be expressed as
$$ 
\lambda^2- tr(A)\lambda + \det(A)=0 \, ,
$$
where $tr(A)$ is the trace of $A$?  Please help I'm not even sure where to begin...

Comment: Well, a good place to start is the definition of the characteristic polynomial.  How do you compute it?

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the characteristic polynomial, we calculate
$$det(A-\lambda I).$$ In this case we have:
$$\begin{pmatrix} a-\lambda & b \\ c& d-\lambda \end{pmatrix}.$$ can you find the determinant of that? After that just keep in mind that the trace is the sum of the diagonals.